# Problems getting Bootstrap 3 button group to properly trigger an accordion

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, accordion

I'm trying to create a page in bootstrap that will have a list of two-button groups. The primary button will trigger an event I'm going to write later, but the goal is to have the button on the right of the button group (which looks like a dropdown button) to trigger an accordion under the button.

I have got it more or less working with the following issues:
1) For some reason, the left side of the button group has rounded corners and the right side has sharp edges. Not a big deal, but irritating.

2)There are some strange visual effects when triggering the accordion open. For a split second it appears to expand indefinitely, with strange lines on the right side of the box. Then everything snaps back to the way it's supposed to look.

3) When collapsing the open accordion, the div simply disappears instead of smoothly scrolling back up.

4) There is a strange line below the second button, which I presume has something to do with the accordion panel but I'm not sure.

Any help or hints would be appreciated. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div align="center">
  <div class="accordion" id="myAccordion">
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="btn-group btn-block btn-group-lg">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-main-title">
          Button 1
        </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-main-dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-1" data-parent="#myAccordion">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <div id="collapsible-1" class="collapse">
        <div style="background-color:#dff0d8;">Nulla vel imperdiet elit. Nullam et diam nulla. Duis nunc orci, gravida vel pellentesque ac, bibendum vitae enim. Aliquam ullamcorper rutrum est, nec luctus eros posuere in. Suspendisse molestie enim eget ante facilisis vehicula. Duis quis consectetur massa. Aliquam sit amet turpis eget metus rutrum pellentesque id eget eros. Aliquam et eros non justo porttitor scelerisque ut ut neque. Ut ultricies mauris sit amet enim iaculis, sed varius nisl varius. Nunc sed urna non enim lobortis sodales sed nec nisl. Duis commodo luctus massa eu interdum. Fusce laoreet ac massa eget sollicitudin. Duis in ligula commodo lectus dictum laoreet vel ac quam.</div>
      </div>
    </div>      

    <div class="btn-group btn-block btn-group-lg">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-main-title">
        Button 2
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-main-dropdown" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible-2" data-parent="#myAccordion">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <div id="collapsible-2" class="collapse">
        <div style="background-color:#dff0d8;">Nulla vel imperdiet elit. Nullam et diam nulla. Duis nunc orci, gravida vel pellentesque ac, bibendum vitae enim. Aliquam ullamcorper rutrum est, nec luctus eros posuere in. Suspendisse molestie enim eget ante facilisis vehicula. Duis quis consectetur massa. Aliquam sit amet turpis eget metus rutrum pellentesque id eget eros. Aliquam et eros non justo porttitor scelerisque ut ut neque. Ut ultricies mauris sit amet enim iaculis, sed varius nisl varius. Nunc sed urna non enim lobortis sodales sed nec nisl. Duis commodo luctus massa eu interdum. Fusce laoreet ac massa eget sollicitudin. Duis in ligula commodo lectus dictum laoreet vel ac quam.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-main-title {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: left;
}

.btn-main-dropdown {
  width: 15%;
}
```

Bootply: http://bootply.com/104455

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `<div id="collapsible-1" class="collapse">` outside of the `<div class="btn-group btn-block btn-group-lg">`

It was the `collapse` being inside of the `btn-group` that seems to be causing your problems...

http://bootply.com/104468

```
<div class="accordion" id="myAccordion">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="btn-group btn-block btn-group-lg">
           <button>...</button>
           <button>...</button>
        </div>      

        <div id="collapsible-1" class="collapse">
           <div>Content...</div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I took your idea and recreated it slightly differently, just for funzies.

[My version](http://codepen.io/SchmalzyB/pen/sdnuo)

Comment: Very slick. Thanks so much for your help!